# insert 2 select sql result into one insert sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table with 2 fields. How can i insert those 2 fields from result of 2 sql result.

```
 insert into access (user,page)
(select id as user from users where id =5,
select pagename as page from pages where id =10)
```

There is no relation between 2  tables . i dont think i can join .

Comment: Is there any sort of relationship between users and pages? Can you give some sample data to show what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into access ("user", page) values
(  (select id as user from users where id =5),
   (select pagename as page from pages where id =10)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into access (user,page)
select users.id as user, 
       pages.pagename as page 
from users,pages
where users.id = 5
  and pages.id = 10
```